# What is the cause of "Empty class name in package" while install app on Android 9.0 emulator?

Tags: android

I develop and test my app in 8.0 system ,everything is ok.
while I built package and it's failed to installed on android 9.0 mobile.
I tried to install on 9.0 emulator and got the following error:

### By the way I tried 5.1 emulator installation successfully.

Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session : INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1560761482.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #68): Empty class name in package com.sdxk.pan.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?

---

I don't understand the meaning of "Empty class name in package com.sdxk.pan.".
And how can I get the useful information about the installation failure clue?

[build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/m1ibZmgn) 
`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
//        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sdxk.pan"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.2.5'

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-gen']
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        starry_data {}
        productFlavors.all { flavor ->
            flavor.manifestPlaceholders = [UMENG_CHANNEL_VALUE: name]
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "defaultConfig"

}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "http://mvn.gt.igexin.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

}


dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:material-spinner:1.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    implementation 'com.zaaach:toprightmenu:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.michaelye.easydialog:easydialog:1.4'
    implementation 'com.youth.banner:banner:1.4.10'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.github.mcxtzhang:SwipeDelMenuLayout:V1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.alibaba:fastjson:1.2.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
    implementation(name: 'android-aespdfview', ext: 'aar')
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:+'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.buyi.recyclerviewpagerindicator:recycler-viewpager-indicator:1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.nikartm:image-support:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.getui:sdk:2.12.5.0'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
    implementation 'com.simple:spiderman:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.scwang.smartrefresh:SmartRefreshLayout:1.1.0-alpha-11'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.flyco.tablayout:FlycoTabLayout_Lib:2.1.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.zhy:autolayout:1.4.5'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.3.0'
    implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.hyman:flowlayout-lib:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.13.1'
    // for experimental rx picker
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:1.13.1'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'cn.aigestudio.datepicker:DatePicker:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.razerdp:BasePopup:2.0.7'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chinalwb:are:0.1.5'
    implementation 'me.gujun.android.taggroup:library:1.4@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.Cutta:TagView:1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.shaoshuai904:iOS_Style_Dialog:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.github.arcadefire:nice-spinner:1.3.7'
    implementation 'com.lzy.net:okgo:+'
    implementation 'com.lzy.widget:imagepicker:0.6.1'
}
```

`

[app Manifest file](https://pastebin.com/cDxEaQpS)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.sdxk.pan">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_USER_PRESENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <!-- Optional for location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>


    <application
        android:name=".CertApplication"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_app"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:appComponentFactory=""
        tools:replace="icon,theme,appComponentFactory">

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ResetPwdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.FlashActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.DocSearchActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MyMaterialActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MyHistoryActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MyFavoriteActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MyVacationActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.VacationDetailActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MyVacationActivity"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.VacationNewActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MyVacationActivity"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MyInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MyTasksActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.TaskDetailActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.MyTasksActivity"
            />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.RewardTasksActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity"
            />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.DocShowActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.DocBasicActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.DocShowActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.DocShowActivity" />

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.DocListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.ReviewActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.ModifyRecordActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.AttachsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <!-- //本地activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalDocSearchActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalPdfActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalImageViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalDocListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalDocShowActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalAttachsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalMusicActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_fault.FaultsSearchActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.CommentsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_fault.FaultsListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <!-- android:hardwareAccelerated="true" -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_fault.FaultShowActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.SystemExpertActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />


        <service
            android:name=".service.UpdateAPPService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.DownloadFileService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.Update3Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.Update4Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.DownloadFile2Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.DownloadFile3Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.MessageCenterService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_fault.LocalFaultsSearchActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_fault.LocalFaultsListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_fault.LocalFaultShowActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.mine.ModifyPersonalInformationActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name=".service.DownloadVideoService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
        <!-- android:hardwareAccelerated="true" -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.VideoOnlineActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|navigation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.DownloadListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name=".service.DownloadQueueService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.AttachCompleteListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.NewLocalVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <service
            android:name=".service.DownloadQueue2Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_local_doc.LocalVideoListActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <service
            android:name=".service.DownloadQueue3Service"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_fault.Fault_VideoOnline_FullScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.VideoOnline2Activity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|navigation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_fault.Fault_VideoOnlineActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|navigation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activity_expert_system.review_module.Review_writeActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.mine.FeedbackActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />



        <activity android:name=".activity.mine.AboutActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/MyAppCompat_NoActionBar"/>

        <!--
 ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".activity.PullDownSearchMenuActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activity.HomeActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.ExpertProfileActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MessageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.AppSettingsActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity_expert_system.review_module.ReviewsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity_expert_system.activity_online_doc.DocShowActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.RewardDetailActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.RewardTasksActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".activity.MyCollectionActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.HomeActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.MaterialNewActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".activity.MyCollectionActivity" />

        </activity>


        <!-- 调整二维码扫描界面为竖屏 -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            tools:replace="screenOrientation" />

        <service
            android:name=".service.EUPushService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="PushService"
            android:process=":pushservice">
        </service>

        <service android:name=".service.EUIntentService"/>

        <!--<meta-data android:name="design_width" android:value="1080">-->
        <!--</meta-data>-->
        <!--<meta-data android:name="design_height" android:value="1920">-->
        <!--</meta-data>-->

        <meta-data android:name="design_width" android:value="750">
        </meta-data>
        <meta-data android:name="design_height" android:value="1334">
        </meta-data>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have a look at line 68 in the merged manifest under your app's `build` directory.

Comment: yes, It's really helpful to locate the line by @laalto 's suggestion. Here is the cause. I leave the value blank. after removing the attribute, the problem is solved. android:appComponentFactory="" tools:replace="icon,theme,appComponentFactory">

Answer (score 4):

For someone stumbling here,
I had the same problem when app was not installing in Android 9.0

The problem was `android:appComponentFactory=""` (it is empty in the merged manifest as shown in line #68) and failing to install on Android 9.0 (works fine below Pie)

The solution was to remove `appComponentFactory` from **`tools:replace="icon,theme,appComponentFactory"`**

If it still fails, try migrating to androidx. However above solution worked for me.

Comment: you are a super hero

Comment: You saved my day. Delicious solution.